# Perf causing program to exit unexpectedly with code 255

Tags: c++, profiling, perf

I'm running a C++ program with [perf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux)), causing it to exit unexpectedly with return code 255. The command I used to run *perf* is the following:

```
perf record --freq=997 --call-graph dwarf -q -o /tmp/xxxperf foo
```

The exit occurs at seemingly random points in execution. I am on [EndeavourOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EndeavourOS), and my kernel version is 6.5.6-arch2-1.

When running the program without *perf*, the program runs fine and exits normally. Why is this happening?

**EDIT**: I noticed that clearing my /tmp folder increased the time before perf terminated. Before clearing, my tmpfs was completely full. Could perf be crashing because it doesn't have enough space to write the output to the tmp folder?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with any other programs like `awk`, or is it specific to this one program which you haven't described at all?  Is it possible it's multi-threaded and has timing-sensitive bugs?  It doesn't happen for me with `perf record --freq=997 --call-graph dwarf -q -o /tmp/xxxperf  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'` on 6.5.3-arch1-1

Comment: The program isn't multithreaded, it's doing nothing particularly strange, just running some search algorithms on a graph.

Comment: Where / how does it crash?  IIRC you can't run it under a debugger while `perf` is already attached to it, but you should be able to get it to dump a core file which you can examine.  Or does it actually exit with a normal exit system call?

Comment: My guess would be underlying undefined behaviour being triggered by perf, try running with sanitizers enabled

Comment: To get that core dump that @PeterCordes suggests (and I concur), typically you'd need to raise the core file size limit with "ulimit -c unlimited", for example, in the same shell, before running perf again.